# How to properly implement a function with variadic number of std::string_view arguments?

Tags: c++, c++17, variadic-templates, variadic-functions

#### Desired behavior

What I basically want is to create a function like this:

```
void func(std::string_view... args)
{
    (std::cout << ... << args);
}
```

It should be able to work **only** with classes that are convertible to `std::string_view`.

Example:

```
int main()
{
    const char* tmp1 = "Hello ";
    const std::string tmp2 = "World";
    const std::string_view tmp3 = "!";

    func(tmp1, tmp2, tmp3, "\n");

    return 0;
}
```

should print: `Hello World!`

---

#### Accomplished behavior

So far, I got here:

```
template<typename... types>
using are_strings = std::conjunction<std::is_convertible<types, std::string_view>...>;

template<typename... strings, class = std::enable_if_t<are_strings<strings...>::value, void>>
void func(strings... args)
{
    (std::cout << ... << args);
}

int main()
{
    const char* tmp1 = "Hello ";
    const std::string tmp2 = "World";
    const std::string_view tmp3 = "!";

    func(tmp1, tmp2, tmp3, "\n");

    return 0;
}
```

This actually works as expected, but there is still one big problem.

---

#### Problem

Only classes that are convertible to `std::string_view` can be used in this function and that's great.
However, even though classes are convertible, they are **not** converted to `std::string_view`!

This leads to needless copying of data(for example when `std::string` is passed as argument).

---

#### Question

Is there a way to force implicit conversion of variadic arguments to `std::string_view`?

---

#### Note

I know about `std::initializer_list`, but I would like to keep function call simple, without `{}`.

Comment: Would passing the arguments via (const?) reference be an option?

Comment: It is certainly my backup plan :D I am not sure how `std::string_view` responds to references since it adds another redirection to the class that basically is just a reference. Nevertheless, I am generally interested if there is a way of forcing implicit conversion to variadic arguments. Anyway, thanks for suggestion!

Comment: If `func` has no return value and you do not need to take its address you can do this https://wandbox.org/permlink/vx7KlBhBhU6icMiF

Comment: Thank you for the help, but https://www.godbolt.org shows that your solution actually generates more assembly. Const reference looks like a better solution, unless you know some example(of main program) where your function would outperform the given one?

Comment: @Iskustvo the assemblies are exactly the same for me https://godbolt.org/z/QolK6c. It is the sign that you can use either one without performance differences in a general case.

Comment: I have never tried anything like this with variadic functions, but here's one way of achieving the same effect: https://ideone.com/r6JwGy You basically use a macro that wraps the arguments into a `std::vector`, and the elements will be implicitly transformed to the desired type if possible.

Comment: @Iskustvo out of curiosity -- why won't you just accept forwarding references, and operate on them?

Comment: @NikitaKniazev, your godbold link has two solutions, but neither was the original one, from my question :D
Havenard, thank you, but the point is that my library provide simple use of function, without lose of performance, the code of the function was just an example...
PiotrSkotnicki, I wasn't sure about performance of const std::string_view& and I wanted to know if it is possible to force implicit conversions, but looking at complexity of other solutions, I'll probably stick with const references.

Comment: @Iskustvo I'm not talking about const references, I'm asking about forwarding references that deduce the exact type and encode value categories of argument expressions

Comment: @PiotrSkotnicki, Mostly because I don't understand quite a bit of offered answers and I need time to investigate it and understand what's happening. Sorry for wasting your time.

Comment: @Iskustvo I'm just suggesting that you could probably get away with `template <typename... Ts> void func(Ts&&...) { /*code*/ }`, I suspect you don't need to force that conversion to `string_view` at all, though I don't know your exact use case

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
namespace impl{
  template<class...SVs>
  void func(SVs... svs){
    static_assert( (std::is_same< SVs, std::string_view >{} && ...) );
    // your code here
  }
}
template<class...Ts,
  std::enable_if_t< (std::is_convertible<Ts, std::string_view >{}&&...), bool > =true
>
void func( Ts&&...ts ){
  return impl::func( std::string_view{std::forward<Ts>(ts)}... );
}
```

or somesuch.

Comment: This looks promising. It still generates a bit more assembly than just adding const& to arguments, at least on few examples I tested it. There is compiler error in `static_assert`, so I removed it. Can you please explain this solution a bit?

Comment: @isku turn inlining up, forcing on non-impl idealy.  I perfect forward to a cast to string view.  Add some brackets and a quoted string to static assert of your compiler is c++11.

Answer (score 2):

```
#include <string_view>
#include <utility>

template <typename>
using string_view_t = std::string_view;

template <typename... Ts>
void func_impl(string_view_t<Ts>... args)
{
    (std::cout << ... << args);
}

template <typename... Ts>
auto func(Ts&&... ts)
    -> decltype(func_impl<Ts...>(std::forward<Ts>(ts)...))
{
    return func_impl<Ts...>(std::forward<Ts>(ts)...);
}
```

[**DEMO**](https://wandbox.org/permlink/yJMRA7fFqehEAYio)

Answer (score 2):

If you simply want to avoid needless copying of data, use a forward reference and then perform explicit casts (if still required). This way no data is copied but forwarded (in your main.cpp example, all params are passed as const references)

```
template <typename... strings,
          class = std::enable_if_t<are_strings<strings...>::value, void>>
void func(strings&&... args) {
  (std::cout << ... << std::string_view{args});
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Not exactly what you asked... but if you can set a superior limit for a the length of `args...` (9 in following example) I propose the following solution: a `foo<N>` struct that inherit `N` `func()` static function that accepting 0, 1, 2, ..., N `std::string_view`.

This way, `func()` function are accepting what is convertible to `std::string_view` and all argument are converted to `std::string_view`.

That is exactly

```
void func(std::string_view... args)
{ (std::cout << ... << args); }
```

with the difference that `func()` functions are `static` methods inside `foo<N>`, that there is a limit in `args...` length and that there is a `func()` method for every supported length.

The full example is the following.

```
#include <string>
#include <utility>
#include <iostream>
#include <type_traits>

template <std::size_t ... Is>
constexpr auto getIndexSequence (std::index_sequence<Is...> is)
   -> decltype(is);

template <std::size_t N>
using IndSeqFrom = decltype(getIndexSequence(std::make_index_sequence<N>{}));

template <typename T, std::size_t>
struct getType
 { using type = T; };

template <typename, typename>
struct bar;

template <typename T, std::size_t ... Is>
struct bar<T, std::index_sequence<Is...>>
 {
   static void func (typename getType<T, Is>::type ... args)
    { (std::cout << ... << args); }
 };

template <std::size_t N, typename = std::string_view, 
          typename = IndSeqFrom<N>>
struct foo;

template <std::size_t N, typename T, std::size_t ... Is>
struct foo<N, T, std::index_sequence<Is...>> : public bar<T, IndSeqFrom<Is>>...
 { using bar<T, IndSeqFrom<Is>>::func ...; };


int main ()
 {
    const char* tmp1 = "Hello ";
    const std::string tmp2 = "World";
    const std::string_view tmp3 = "!";

    foo<10u>::func(tmp1, tmp2, tmp3, "\n");
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

Make it a two-stage production:

```
template <class... Args>
std::enable_if_t<... && std::is_same<Args, std::string_view>()>
func(Args... args)
{
    (std::cout << ... << args);
}

template <class... Args>
auto func(Args&&... args)
-> std::enable_if_t<... || !std::is_same<std::decay_t<Args>, std::string_view>(),
    decltype(func(std::string_view(std::forward<Args>(args))...))>
{
    func(std::string_view(std::forward<Args>(args))...);
}
```